# Decoding function to better understand

Tags: php, for-loop

I am revisiting PHP and want to relearn where i lack and i found one problem, i am unable to understand the following code, where as it should output `6` according to the quiz, i got it from but i broke it down to simple pieces and commented out to better understand, according to me the value of $sum should be `4`, but what i am doing wrong, maybe my breakdown is wrong?

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4);

$total = count($numbers);
//$total = 4
$sum = 0;

$output = "";

$i = 0;

foreach($numbers as $number) {

    $i = $i + 1;
        //0+1 = 1
        //0+2 = 2
        //0+3 = 3
        //0+4 = 4


    if ($i < $total) {

        $sum = $sum + $number;

        //1st time loop = 0 < 4 false
        //2nd time loop = 0 < 1 false
        //3rd time loop = 0 < 2 false
        //5th time loop = 0 < 3 false
        //6th time loop = 4 = 4 true
            //$sum + $number
            //0 + 4
            //4
    }

}

echo $sum;
```

This is very basic question and might get down vote but it is also a strong backbone for people who want to become PHP developer.

Comment: When you do `$i = $i + 1;`, the `$i` is no longer `0` as you have in your commented out `0+1 = 1`,`0+2=2`,etc.

Comment: Your commented code is very good.  Unfortunately, the 2nd set of commens is WRONG: `//1st time loop = 2 == true`, etc.  So "sum" is actually getting incremented before 6th time loop.  ALSO: you never get past "4th time loop"; there aren't 6 items in your array.

Comment: `if ($i < $total)` is true the 1st (`$sum = 0 + 1 = 1`) , 2nd (`$sum = 1 + 2 = 3`) and 3rd time (`$sum = 3 + 3 = 6`). Is that clear?

Comment: @Rasclatt oh boy, my maths is weak. I thought 0+1 is 0 and so. Must be tired.

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand the last part in the loop. It actually goes like this now:

```
if($i < $total) {
    $sum = $sum + $number;
    //1st time loop: $sum is 0. $sum + 1 = 1. $sum is now 1.
    //2nd time loop: $sum is 1. $sum + 2 = 3. $sum is now 3.
    //3rd time loop: $sum is 3. $sum + 3 = 6. $sum is now 6.

    //4th time loop: it doesn't get here. $i (4) < $total (4)
    //This is false, so it doesn't execute this block.
}

echo $sum; // Output: 6
```

Comment: I was missing 2 things, one was i was doing addition in wrong way. second which i haven't understood. How can `$sum` retain value from last result of `$sum`, i thought it was always `0+1`, `0+2` , `0+3` and while `$number` is a `array()`, how can it break out of it and count it as a individual numbers?

Comment: That is because $sum is declared outside the foreach loop below `$total`. Please explain what you're trying to achieve. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to understand the breakdown of this function as its really hard for me to understand the breakdown as o m weak in loops

Answer (score 1):

I altered your script a little so that it will print out what it's doing as it goes. I find it useful to do this kind of thing if I'm having a hard time thinking through a problem.

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4);

$total = count($numbers);
$sum = 0;

$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($numbers as $number) {
    $i = $i + 1;
    echo "Iteration $j: \$i +1 is $i, \$sum is $sum, \$number is $number";
    if ($i < $total) {
        $sum = $sum + $number;
        echo ", \$i is less than \$total ($total), so \$sum + \$number is: $sum";
    } else {
        echo ", \$i is not less than \$total ($total), so \$sum will not be increased.";
    }
    echo '<br>'; // or a new line if it's CLI
    $j++;
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: This is really good way to get a detailed output. Not much advance to write something like this but great!

Answer (score 0):

**Lets Explain**

Your initial value of $i is 0 but when you start looping you increment it by 1, so the start value of $i is 1.

When checking the condition you did't use equal sign to check for the last value whether you start value is 1. So its clear that your loop must be run for 1 less of total.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($numbers as $number) {
    $i += 1;
    if ($i < $total)        
        $sum += $number;
}
echo $sum;
```

**Analysis**

```
Step: 1 / 4
The value of $number is: 1 And The value of $i is: 1

Step: 2 / 4
The value of $number is: 2 And The value of $i is: 2

Step: 3 / 4
The value of $number is: 3 And The value of $i is: 3
```

When the loop again go for a check the value of $i increased by 1 and at 4. So trying to match the condition `if ($i < $total)`, where the value of $i and $total is equal, so it will return false. So the loop only run for 3 time.

**Result**

> 6

Comment: I am trying to figure out breakdown of `if` loop, how and why does it store value of last element.